# Constraints are not working correctly with view and custom xib-file

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints

I am using a ratreeview with a `custom xib`. Unfortunately the autolayouconstraints are not working correctly.

1) I set constraints to the view: its a simply view with constraints to the margins
[image]

2) I created a xib-file with a label and an image. On both I have set the margins and a vertical space between them. Additionaly I set the hugging for the label to 230.
[image]

3) Here the output. Unfortunately the constraints are not working correctly. Why? `Size classes` are set correctly to for with and height to any, any. 
[image]

thanks, arnold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you instanitating the tableview cell? It looks like you are instantiating a standard tableview cell.

Your code should look more like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CUSTOMCELLNAME" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       return cell;
}
```

So probably replace the customcell name with "pHeaderCell"

Looking further into it, in your case, instead of creating the cell from the tableview, you will need to get the **view from your xib** file in this delegate method.

Comment: Thanks. The error was that I missed to set the right frame for RATreeview!